# Vibrant.js library not loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to use a js library but am having trouble getting it connected.
https://github.com/Vibrant-Colors/node-vibrant

Downloaded vibrant.js using node.
Js file: `var Vibrant = require(['node-vibrant']);`

Html file (added this so I can ise require above): `<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script>`

And I am getting these errors:
[image: err]

Comment: try this src: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vibrant.js/1.0.0/Vibrant.min.js

Comment: If i include that into my html nothing happens

Comment: Show your RequireJS config. Also, that is note how you would typically use RequireJS.

Comment: Not sure how I can see the config for it. Could you tell me how to get that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here.

First one is that `require()` function does not return the module you are requiring, it works async. So you would have to provide a callback which will be executed when the module is loaded:

```javascript
require(['node-vibrant'], () => {
    console.log('Vibrant is loaded');
});
```

Second thing is your web server does not know what is `/node-vibrant`, you have to provide full path to it. As someone mentioned in comment, you can use CDN:

```javascript
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'node-vibrant': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vibrant.js/1.0.0/Vibrant.min'
    }
});
require(['node-vibrant'], () => {
    console.log('Vibrant is loaded, you can do what you want with it');
    console.log(window.Vibrant);
});
```

Third thing, which is optional is to set `shim` for this script as it is not AMD module. It won't be injected into your callback, but it will be a global variable. This can be fixed:

```javascript
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'node-vibrant': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vibrant.js/1.0.0/Vibrant.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'node-vibrant': {
            'exports': 'Vibrant'
        }
    }
});
require(['node-vibrant'], (Vibrant) => {
    console.log('Vibrant is loaded and injected, you can do what you want with it');
    console.log(Vibrant);
});
```